# Linear Algebra Linear transformation Help

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, diagonalization

If $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation, then there exists a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which $T$ is diagonal.

Is this true or false

Answer (score 1):

No, assume $T$ represented by (in standard basis)
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

There is no basis in which this matrix is diagonal.